# PHP/Mysql -> AVG of billing/paydate per User

Tags: php, mysql, average, datediff

I have two tables: 
t_address -> With Users addresses
t_billing -> With billing information for the t_address users

They are linked by t_billing.bil_addressref = t_address.adr_ref

In the billing table, i have a field
bil_date -> Date when bill has been issued/sent
bil_paydate -> Date when bill has been payed

I would no like to determine the "worst Payers", meaning the ones who Need the average longest time to pay the bill.

e.g.:

No. -- bil_date -- bil_paydate -- adr_ref
1 -- 2017-01-01 -- 2017-01-10 - 1
2 -- 2017-02-01 -- 2017-02-10 - 1
3 -- 2017-03-01 -- 2017-03-05 - 1
4 -- 2017-04-01 -- 2017-04-05 - 1
5 -- 2017-01-01 -- 2017-01-30 - 2
6 -- 2017-03-01 -- 2017-03-30 - 2
...

So 
for adr 2 the avg pay-time is 29 days
for adr 1 the avg pay-time is 6.5 days

I'd like to have the TOP 5 results of worst Payers, ordered from worst to less worst.

I tried several queries and ideas but didn't come accross the correct idea :/

any suggestions? Thanks, Stephan.

Comment: Can you show us what queries you've tried so far?

Comment: Last attempt was getting all adr_ref distinct in t_billing where paydate IS NOT NULL and then this in a while (knowing it would not lead to my wanted result). didn't even get a value for amt :/  `SELECT bil_addressref, adr_lastname, adr_firstname, AVG(DATEDIFF(TO_DAYS(bil_paydate),TO_DAYS(bil_date))) AS avg, adr_ref  FROM t_billing
         INNER JOIN t_address ON bil_addressref = adr_ref
         
         WHERE bil_mandantref='$mandantref'
         AND bil_addressref='".$rowWorstPayerMain['bil_addressref']."'
         GROUP BY bil_addressref
         ORDER BY avg ASC`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a join , group by and limit

```
  select adr_ref,  sum( datediff(bil_paydate,bil_date ))/ count(*) my_result
  from t_address
  inner join  t_billing on t_billing.bil_addressref = t_address.adr_ref

  group by adr_ref
  order by  my_result desc 
  limit 5
```

Comment: that seems to work, thanks. had to add a 'AND bil_paydate IS NOT NULL' to get proper results. Why does AVG not work for this? MH, Problem seemed, that i started with t_billing and joined t_address instead of the other way round...